SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session with Chrome browser Version 123.0.6312.106
I am getting the following exception while trying to execute code using the Chrome browser Version 123.0.6312.106 (64-bit)
Code:
package com.test.org;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Test {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           
            options.addArguments( "--remote-debugging-pipe" );
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
            options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
            String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
            String actualTitle = "";

            // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
            driver.get(baseUrl);

            // get the actual value of the title
            actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

            /*
             * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
             * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
             */
            if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
                System.out.println("com.test.org.Test Passed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("com.test.org.Test Failed");
            }

            //close Fire fox
            driver.close();
        }
}

Error :
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000 
Host info: host: 'UKC-3HTNSL3', ip: '192.168.0.26'
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --remote-debugging-pipe], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Goog..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:61)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at com.test.org.Test.main(Test.java:18)

> Task :Test.main() FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Test.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Output :


try with no options set and then add them back in one at a time.  I'd suspect this one: --remote-debugging-pipe  What's the use-case for that?

@browsermator : I already tried everything
